# vue-class-component: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-class-components

Ok, it's a weird usecase, but in any case.

I have a controls component, that includes menu component, that also includes a controls component but without menu (strange stuff, but that's design).

What I do.

Controls component:

```
import {Component, Prop, Vue} from 'vue-property-decorator'
import Burger from "./Burger";
import ShadowLogo from "./ShadowLogo";
import MegaMenu from "./MegaMenu";

@Component
export default class Controls extends Vue {
  @Prop({default: false})
  showMenu: boolean;

  renderLogo(h) {
    return <div class="logo"><ShadowLogo/></div>
  }

  renderBurger(h) {
    return <Burger opened={this.showMenu} label="меню" on-want-change={e => this.$emit('show-menu', !this.showMenu)}></Burger>
  }

  renderFooter(h) {
    return <div class="copyrights"></div>
  }

  renderMenu(h) {
    return <div class="menu-layer">
      {this.showMenu ? <transition name="fade" appear={true}><MegaMenu/></transition> : null}
    </div>
  }

  render(h) {
    return <div class={["control-overlay", this.showMenu ? 'menu-opened' : null]}>
      {this.renderMenu(h)}
      {this.renderLogo(h)}
      {this.renderBurger(h)}
      {this.renderFooter(h)}
    </div>
  }
}
```

Menu inner controls component to be inserted inside the menu — the same, but without menu component (to prevent recursion, obviously)

```
import Controls from "./Controls";
import {Component} from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component
export default class MenuInnerControls extends Controls {
  renderMenu(h) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

But in this setup I get en error:

```
51:13 Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined
    at _inherits (51:13)
    at eval (51:19)
    at eval (MenuInnerControls.js?9737:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:394)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at eval (22:4)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:219)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at eval (18:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:192)
```

(MenuInnerControls.js?9737:8 — is the renderMenu method in inherited class)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Vue decorators, but could it be that you must implement the constructor and call super?

Comment: @MaartenBicknese nope

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, figured out that problem was in circular dependencies in imports. `Controls` renders `MegaMenu` that renders `MenuInnerControls`  that extend `Controls`.
And even so `MenuInnerControls` does not refer to `MegaMenu`, this causes circular dependency in imports. Should not be an issue in other languages, but js... oh